# Google Calendar API: Display Name doesn't work

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am faced with a strange problem: `displayName` property is not applied/saved on event level. Here is a link to the API documentation: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events

I fill in the `displayName` for the organizer and attendee in the event and then save this event. But in emails displayName is nowhere showing. I expect to see it ideally in the email as `<{DisplayName}>@organizer` email. That's an issue I am trying to solve but I see it nowhere at all. I read this event from google calendar using event id. And there's no property `displayName` in organizer and attendees fields.

I double checked and I use v3 of the Calendar API, so I believe I am checking documentation for the same API version I use in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you create a Events resource and want to get the values for `organizer.displayName` and `attendees[].displayName`. In that case, then everything is working as described. In the Events resource it is stated that those properties are subject to disponibility. Also, in the case of `attendees[].displayName`, it is optional too. Both properties are writable, so ideally you could include them in your requests. Please, ask me any additional doubts.

Comment: hi Jacques
I need to be able to set up displayName. But it doesn't work. I send displayName, I debugged using logging and google api service sends this data to Google calendar API. But, when I fetch data about this event from Google API after it is created, there's no displayName at all.

Comment: But initial issue I am trying to solve is: no person name surname shown in the From Header in google calendar invitations. I am thinking that if I send displayName, specify it while creating event, it may solve the problem....

Comment: Hi @SergeyGlazyrin ! To better study your question, could you please share the API requests/responses involved?

Answer (score 0):

the answer lies in the Google+ replacement, "Currents".  If you have Google Apps for Business, make sure Currents is available for your users, and then from within Currents, make sure the users you want to have the 'displayName' appear for have an "active profile". As an admin for the organization, you can make profiles active on users' behalf. Once they have an active profile under Currents, the "displayName" will use the name associated with the account.