# Is it possible to get display name from google account email

Tags: api, google-api, google-calendar-api

**Abstract**

I develop a Google API integration for a Saas product.
One of its functions is to retrieve the email and displayName of the participants of an event registered in Google Calendar.(ref 1, same issue is reported)

At first　I try to get email and display name from get method for google calendar events resources,but I found that many event participants have an email but no displayName.( ref 2,3 )

Then, I try to use google people api to get displayName from email but I couldn't find the way to get it.

**Question**
If you know the way to get displayName from google account email, please tell me how to do it.

**Reference**

1. [Google Calendar API: Display Name doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64972472/google-calendar-api-display-name-doesnt-work)
2. [Google Calendar API, Events Resource representations](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events)
3. [Google Calendar API, Events Resource representations](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get)

Answer (score 0):

- The `displayName` availability depends either from that account's Name set at [Google profile](https://myaccount.google.com/profile)) or from the API caller's contact List in [Google Contact](https://contacts.google.com/).
- If the caller and the affected account are within the same Google Workspace environment, then the domain's user profile Name is taken into account.
- If that account is added to the caller's Contacts, then it is also possible to retrieve its Display Name via People API.
- If the affected account doesn't have a name set nor it is within the caller's contacts, that's expected behavior.